# Why should @font-face be declared at global scope, outside of shadow DOM?

Tags: html, css, font-face, shadow-dom

I know by experience that `@font-face` should be declared at global scope, outside of shadow DOM, however, I cannot find any specification about it. Can anyone provide explanation with plausible source or the documentation/specs?

I understand there are many similar questions and answers, but AFAIK none of them actually provides any official reference.

Comment: Is this the answer to your question? https://css-tricks.com/regarding-css-global-scope/

Comment: `@font-face` can be declared within a [conditional group rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule#conditional_group_rules), like `@media` and `@supports`, not just at the global scope. I've not heard of a restriction from shadow DOM.

Comment: @ErfanBahramali It didn't give me the answer that I was looking for, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm not talking about at-rule level of scope here, but more likely global-shadow DOM level scope. If you try to load fonts using `@font-face` inside of a shadow DOM, it just doesn't load, no matter you do it inside of `@media` or `@supports` (at least on the latest Chrome). And the thing which we don't agree with the existence of this issue is the very reason why I asked this question. Where is the spec stating this? Couldn't find any documentation on w3.org, mozilla, etc. Hope you come back with the evidence and I will greatly appreciate ;)

Comment: Ask at the source: https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues?q=is%3Aissue+font-face

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thank you, that's a good idea that I haven't thought about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is still an open draft as of May 2021. The entire discussion can be found here: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1995